# How to append an <li> to a <ul> and set css on the <li> at the same time with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following sets the color on the `<ul>` I am appending the `<li>` to. I want the set the color of the `<li>` being appended instead:

```
$('.test').append(
    '<li class="asdf" data-blerg="ssdkf">TESTESETSETSERT</li>').css('color', 'blue');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7rQwn/)

Comment: you could do that with in-line css, so with style="" inside your <li>

Comment: Look at what your object chaining is doing. You're selecting the .test element(s) then appending an element, then changing the css attribute, all actions are happening to the originally selected element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this with [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) instead:

```
$('<li class="asdf" data-blerg="ssdkf">TESTESETSETSERT</li>')
   .css('color', 'blue').appendTo('.test');
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/7rQwn/1/)

You can also keep using `append()` like this:

```
$('.test').append($('<li class="asdf" data-blerg="ssdkf">TESTESETSETSERT</li>')
                .css('color', 'blue'));
```

Comment: Cool, I think that way (creating the node first and then appending it) looks like its easier to read as well.

Comment: @user1028270 yes, it depends on the context when you write code.

Comment: Is one way significantly faster? I'm doing this many times on the page maybe as much as 100 times as I'm appending a lot of list items.

Comment: @user1028270 I think the speed would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like:

```
var el = $('<li class="asdf" data-blerg="ssdkf">TESTESETSETSERT</li>');
$('.test').append($(el).css('color', 'blue'));
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7rQwn/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way as I find it is a bit neater if you want to add multiple element attributes, I think it will also touch the dom less.

```
var listItem = $('<li/>', {
    html: 'TESTESETSETSERT',
    class : 'asdf',
    'data-blerg' : 'ssdkf'
});
$('.test').append(listItem);
```

Example here 
http://jsfiddle.net/7rQwn/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you append a new element this is the last child of DOM. The method append return the container, you need to get them childrem,  get last child and appl you css

```
$('.test').append(
    '<li class="asdf" data-blerg="ssdkf">TESTESETSETSERT</li>').children().last().css('color', 'blue');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D3EgK/1/